# System.ArgumentException when calling MediaLibrary.SavePicture()

Tags: silverlight, exception, windows-phone-7, xna, media-library

My code looks like this:

```
String filename = Utils.GetNextFilename();
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
library.SavePicture(filename, corrected_image);
```

And in the `SavePicture()` call, I get the following:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.Xna.Framework.dll
>
> Additional information: Value does not
>   fall within the expected range.

But I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.  I must reset the stream:

```
String filename = Utils.GetNextFilename();
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
corrected_image.Seek(0, 0);                      // <-- The fix.
library.SavePicture(filename, corrected_image);
```